# How does Microsoft implement automated properties without "set"? (c#)

Tags: c#-4.0

As I understand, when using automated properties, one must write both set and get methods.
However, when I look at Microsoft's System.Exception, there are some properties that clearly does not follow this demand, for instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx.

Can someone please explain me how can this be?

Comment: int MyProperty {get; private set;}

Comment: That's because it is actually passed in on several of the constructors. This makes it immutable - once it is passed in you cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an automatic property, one never writes set and get methods.  The compiler provides both for you.

If you see a property without a set, or without a get, it was defined the long way, and not an automatic property.

The fact that the backing property is a legal C# name, and not a compiler-reserved name, is another clue that you're looking at a manual property.  So is the fact that this property has been around since long before automatic properties were implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry?

What about "no public set"?

Can be.... protected or  private and thus be filtered in the documentation.

Comment: `System.Exception.InnerException` has no setter at all, as opposed to one that's restricted access.